# bash script for grep with context

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Am writing a bash script that uses grep to search phrases and prints them on terminal.  I want the user to have the possibility of using the context options of grep (`-C`, `-A`, `-B`).  I made an indexed array `ictx`, which I want to use for making the context arguments to grep (`-C NUM`, `-A NUM`, `-B NUM`, `-A NUM1 -B NUM2`).

Would help having some advice on how I can neatly handle the making of `ictx` with tho code listed below.

```
  while (( $# > 0 )); do
   case "$1" in
     ("-C"|"--context")
         ctx="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
    
     ("--Bfc"|"--before-context")
         bfctx="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;

     ("--Afc"|"--after-context")
         afctx="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
   esac
  done

  ictx=()
  [ -n "$bfctx" ] && ictx+=( -B "$bfctx" )
  [ -n "$afctx" ] && ictx+=( -A "$afctx" )

  [[ -z "$ctx" ]] && ctx=8
  (( ${#ictx[@]} == 0 )) && ictx+=( -C "$ctx" )

  grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "$fl"
```

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu but is about bash scripting. It may better fit on stackoverflow.com with tag `bash`. You should describe what user input should result in what `grep` command.  You can use shellcheck.net to check a shell script for errors.

Comment: bash scripting is always on topic: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic.

Comment: I can use `+=` to add the options to the array, but want to avoid conflicts.

Comment: You may want to use an associative array where the option becomes the key, e.g., `array[B]=$bfctx`. You can then use it in a statement `[[ -z ${array[B]+ } ]]`

Comment: Just set the array directly instead of appending to it if you want to avoid conflicts? `[ -n "$bfctx" ] && ictx=( -B "$bfctx" ); [ -n "$afctx" ] && ictx=( -A "$afctx" )` and so on? Or better yet, just do so in the case statement instead of setting a temporary variable and then checking it.